# Customizing PyQt Qscintilla CPP lexer

Tags: python, pyqt, keyword, lexer, qscintilla

I'm writing an RSL editor for a personal project, and i'd like to customize the CPP lexer available in QScintilla because all i need is just a few extra keywords to be highlighted, but i cant really find out how to add them.

any help?
cheers

edit - Ive been playing with snippets ive found and ive managed to get new keywords to work by subclssing the CPP lexer and creating a key set, but it only works if o overwrite the existing keyset on index 1

from PyQt4 import Qsci

```
class RSLLexer(Qsci.QsciLexerCPP): 
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        super(RSLLexer, self).__init__()

def keywords(self, keyset):
    if keyset == 1:
        return b'surface'
    return Qsci.QsciLexerCPP.keywords(self, keyset)
```

Comment: Might be helpful: http://qscintilla.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subclass of `QsciLexerCPP` and reimplement the [keywords](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciLexerCPP.html#aad460a3dde0be5dd8904729ed1e47826) method:

```
class RSLLexer(Qsci.QsciLexerCPP):
    def keywords(self, index):
        keywords = Qsci.QsciLexerCPP.keywords(self, index) or ''
        # primary keywords
        if index == 1:
            return 'foo ' + keywords
        # secondary keywords
        if index == 2:
            return 'bar ' + keywords
        # doc comment keywords
        if index == 3:
            return keywords
        # global classes
        if index == 4:
            return keywords
        return keywords
```

Each of these keyword sets has a different style associated with it, so they can be highlighted differently. See the [style enumeration](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciLexerCPP.html#a9e207c35eb4d13407b46606e44faa01daaf3761b6b64a02e306095a77c6e44d22) for which ones to use.

Comment: When i try your solution i still don't get the extra keywords to reigtser unless i remove the return mykeywords1 + keywords and replace it with just return mykeywords1.  Whcih still kinda works because i can just print out the original values and re-add them anyway

Comment: @SketchyManDan. I got the indexes wrong: they start at one, not zero! Also, I forgot to guard against the base-class call returning `None`. These two things have now been fixed in my answer, and I've confirmed that they work. One final point: `mykeywords` should end with a space.